# How can i get the height of BottomNavigationView using XML?

Tags: android, material-design, bottomnavigationview

Is there any way to get the height of `BottomNavigationView`height using XML attribute just like this `?attr/actionBarSize`

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/whiteColor"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"
    android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"/>
```

Comment: yes, I have used ?attr/actionBarSize in my app throughout the BottomNavigationView @Manoj

Comment: @BrahmaDatta That's not the exact height of `BottomNavigationView`

Comment: But it is a fixed height if we put wrap_content then the height may increase depending on the Image height. @Manoj

Comment: The `?attr/actionBarSize` is correct for portrait mode but not for landscape mode. I found that the height of the `BottomNavigaitonView` is `56dp` (see here: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/res/values/dimens.xml) you could use `56dp` in your XML but of course this could change over time. I'm looking into it if the `design_bottom_navigation_height` dimension is accessible in XML (haven't found a way yet).